# Append new values to .pkl model

Tags: file, machine-learning, pickle

I fit my machine learning model and then I saved it with pickle in a .pkl file. Now I need to fit my model again, so I need to append new values to my .pkl file. This is the code I tried:

```
pickle.dump(model, open('sentiment_datasets/es.pkl', 'a+'))
```

But I get the following error:

```
write() argument must be string, not bytes
```

How can I fix it? I repeat, I don't need to overwrite my file but append new values

Answer (score 0):

The method `pickle.dump` means converting an object to a byte stream that can be stored. If you trained the model with some new data, the python object was changed (in case of the linear model, the weights of the features were updated). So you have the different python object, that needs to be serialized and stored.

You can't append the new values, you need to save the updated model.

Comment: How can I save the updated model without deleting the progress already done?

Comment: You should save it in a separate file. To be able to track the progress of the model, you can add a specific suffix to the filename. A popular suffix is "date indicator". For instance, model_05_2020.pickle, model_06_2020.pickle, etc.

Comment: So there's no way to fit a model once and store it in a file. Then open the model and fit it again then save it on the same file without losing the first progress....?

Comment: Yes, you can't save a model in the same file without losing the previous state. But if you will save the updated model in the new file, then you can load the previous model.